# How to launch default screen in TabBar React Native

Tags: react-native

**Once my app starts App.js Screen launch in which I have to show GridView 
  and at the bottom, there are 5 Tabs name "Index", "Favourite", "Buying", 
  "Selling", "Preview" and these all 5 tabs have their own views or 
  classes, this gridview is not called by any of these Tabs also when I press Index Tab than index class launch in which there is a back button when I press this button then again Gridview launch is this possible??**